# Moving elements in a list-of-lists in prolog

Tags: list, matrix, prolog

I'm making a 8-puzzle solver in prolog, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to program the rules of the game.
The initial state of the game is represented as a list-of-lists, like: [[2,8,3,],[1,6,4],[7,0,5]].
I need to make the program move the 0 to another position that is adjacent to its initial position, and I have no idea how to do it.
I know how to manipulate lists using nth0, select, append, etc. But have no idea on how to manipulate a matrix(list-of-lists) in prolog.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

I've tried using chatGPT, but it didint help.

```
line_matching([], [], []).
line_matching([X|Y], [X|Z], S):- line_matching(Y, Z, S).
line_matching([X|Y], [W|Z], [X|K]):- line_matching(Y, Z, K).


list_count([], 0).
list_count([X|Y], R):- list_count(Y, R2), R is R2 + 1.


wrong_position(Line, 1, Y):- line_matching(Line, [1, 2, 3], Z), list_count(Z,Y).
wrong_position(Line, 2, Y):- line_matching(Line, [8, 0, 4], Z), list_count(Z,Y).
wrong_position(Line, 3, Y):- line_matching(Line, [7, 6, 5], Z), list_count(Z,Y)
```

I dont know if they are useful for this kind of problem, I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution (which does not need additional libraries):

```
% left/right movements

lr([[0,A,B], L2, L3], [[A,0,B], L2, L3]).
lr([[A,0,B], L2, L3], [[A,B,0], L2, L3]).
lr([L1, [0,A,B], L3], [L1, [A,0,B], L3]).
lr([L1, [A,0,B], L3], [L1, [A,B,0], L3]).
lr([L1, L2, [0,A,B]], [L1, L2, [A,0,B]]).
lr([L1, L2, [A,0,B]], [L1, L2, [A,B,0]]).

% up/down movements

ud([[0,A,B], [C,D,E], L3], [[C,A,B], [0,D,E], L3]).
ud([[A,0,B], [C,D,E], L3], [[A,D,B], [C,0,E], L3]).
ud([[A,B,0], [C,D,E], L3], [[A,B,E], [C,D,0], L3]).
ud([L1, [0,A,B], [C,D,E]], [L1, [C,A,B], [0,D,E]]).
ud([L1, [A,0,B], [C,D,E]], [L1, [A,D,B], [C,0,E]]).
ud([L1, [A,B,0], [C,D,E]], [L1, [A,B,E], [C,D,0]]).

% all movements

mv(rt, Old, New) :- lr(Old, New).
mv(lt, Old, New) :- lr(New, Old).
mv(up, Old, New) :- ud(New, Old).
mv(dn, Old, New) :- ud(Old, New).

% Tests

test(N) :-
    board(N, Old),
    forall(mv(Action, Old, New),
           format('~w --(~w)--> ~w\n', [Old, Action, New])).

board(1, [[2, 8, 3],
          [1, 6, 4],
          [7, 0, 5]]).

board(2, [[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 0, 5],
          [6, 7, 8]]).
```

Examples:

```
?- test(1).
[[2,8,3],[1,6,4],[7,0,5]] --(rt)--> [[2,8,3],[1,6,4],[7,5,0]]
[[2,8,3],[1,6,4],[7,0,5]] --(lt)--> [[2,8,3],[1,6,4],[0,7,5]]
[[2,8,3],[1,6,4],[7,0,5]] --(up)--> [[2,8,3],[1,0,4],[7,6,5]]
true.

?- test(2).
[[1,2,3],[4,0,5],[6,7,8]] --(rt)--> [[1,2,3],[4,5,0],[6,7,8]]
[[1,2,3],[4,0,5],[6,7,8]] --(lt)--> [[1,2,3],[0,4,5],[6,7,8]]
[[1,2,3],[4,0,5],[6,7,8]] --(up)--> [[1,0,3],[4,2,5],[6,7,8]]
[[1,2,3],[4,0,5],[6,7,8]] --(dn)--> [[1,2,3],[4,7,5],[6,0,8]]
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make the program move the 0 to another position that is adjacent to its initial position

There are many ways, I came up with this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).  % provides transpose/2 predicate.


% define adjacent position moves for possible
% places of 0 in a row.

row_moved([0,A,B], [A,0,B]).    % left to middle.
row_moved([A,B,0], [A,0,B]).    % right to middle.

row_moved([A,0,B], [0,A,B]).    % middle to left.
row_moved([A,0,B], [A,B,0]).    % middle to right.

row_moved([A,B,C], [A,B,C]) :-  % no zeros, no move.
    dif(A, 0), dif(B, 0), dif(C, 0).


test(Moved) :-
    Board = [[2, 8, 3],
             [1, 6, 4],
             [7, 0, 5]],

    (  maplist(row_moved, Board, Moved)    % try row_move on all rows.
    ;                                      % OR
      (transpose(Board, BoardColumns),     % try row_move on all columns...
       maplist(row_moved, BoardColumns, Moved_),
       transpose(Moved_, Moved))
    ).
```

e.g.

```
%Board = [[2, 8, 3],
%         [1, 6, 4],
%         [7, 0, 5]],

?- test(Answer).

Answer = [[2, 8, 3], 
          [1, 6, 4],
          [0, 7, 5]]
;
Answer = [[2, 8, 3],
          [1, 6, 4],
          [7, 5, 0]]
;
Answer = [[2, 8, 3],
          [1, 0, 4],
          [7, 6, 5]]
```